# Debug runs fine, but not in release mode

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have an application that runs in the debug build, but when I start it in the release build, I get this error:

```
LINK:fatal error LNK1181:Can not open input file 'Qt5Core5.lib'
```

Comment: Does the command line for both release and debug builds include the location of that lib?

Comment: Well, the obvious question is: do you have the release libraries built? How did you install Qt? What version of Qt is it? What platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting all temporary data created by QtCreator. Has worked for me in that situation.